# Parsing 3-pair elements from a json array

Tags: javascript, json

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/6ruosmx8/

Here is my data ..

```
{
  "Ids":[
    {
      "value0":"Black",
      "value0":"8",
      "Id":"10979"
    },
    {
      "value1":"Black",
      "value1":"9",
      "Id":"10980"
    },
    {
      "value2":"Black",
      "value2":"10",
      "Id":"10981"
    },
    {
      "value3":"Black",
      "value3":"10.5",
      "Id":"10982"
    },
    {
      "value4":"Black",
      "value4":"11",
      "Id":"10983"
    },
    {
      "value5":"Black",
      "value5":"11.5",
      "Id":"10984"
    },
    {
      "value6":"Black",
      "value6":"12",
      "Id":"10985"
    },
    {
      "value7":"Black",
      "value7":"13",
      "Id":"10986"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my logic, trying to parse out each `Id` ..

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
    alert(JSON.stringify(json.Ids[i]));
}
```

Gives me this output ..
`alert()` .. `{"value0":"8","Id":"10979"}`
`alert()` .. `{"value1":"9","Id":"10980"}`
`alert()` .. `{"value2":"10","Id":"10981"}`
..

Why is the output not this? ..
`{"value0": "Black","value0": "8","Id": "10979"}`
`{"value0": "Black","value0": "9","Id": "10980"}`
`{"value0": "Black","value0": "10","Id": "10981"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't repeat they "keys" in key-value pairs. The keys need to be unique. 
The code you have is overwriting/confusing the `valueX` values in each object and only returning the last one that's defined. Change one of the keys in each object and it should show you all 3 key-value pairs.
So

```
{
 "color":"black",  //This 1st property needs to be different from the 2nd one in each object
 "value":"8",
 "Id":"10979"
}
```

Edit - and actually, there's no need to add a number to the keys, since each one is already contained in a separate object w/a unique ID. The current approach makes it harder to list or sort by a particular key, since you have to append the array index to the name of the key. Just define the property in a generic way and save yourself that extra hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate properties in an object.  The second value of each "valueX" property is overwriting the first value.